# Can we save KeyValuePair<K,V> in user profile?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-profiles

```
[Serializable]
public class KeyValue : ProfileBase
{
    public KeyValue() { }

    public KeyValuePair<string, string> KV
    {
        get { return (KeyValuePair<string, string>)base["KV"]; }
        set { base["KV"] = value; }
    }            
}

public void SaveProfileData()
{
    KeyValue profile = (KeyValue) HttpContext.Current.Profile;
    profile.Name.Add(File);
    profile.KV = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "val"); 
    profile.Save();
}   

public void LoadProfile()
{
    KeyValue profile = (KeyValue) HttpContext.Current.Profile;
    string k = profile.KV.Key;
    string v = profile.KV.Value;
    Files = profile.Name;          
}
```

I am trying to save `KeyValuePair<K,V>` in asp.net userprofile and it saves also but when i am accessing it, it show both key and value property null, can anybody tells me where i am wrong?

In `LoadProfile()` k and v are null.

**Web.config**

```
<profile enabled="true" inherits="SiteBuilder.Models.KeyValue">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Comment: I'd try giving it a distinct name from your property, i.e. save and read `["_KV"]` or similar - can't imagine why that might make a difference, but it might for serialization.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a new MVC3 project (i.e. it works fine). Can you provide a complete test case? Otherwise I would recommend that you check your flow - perhaps at the point you're calling LoadProfile(), it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 2):

C#'s `KeyValuePair` has not a public setter for the Key / Value attributes. So it might serialize but it will deserialize empty.

You must create your own little implementation of the class, for example:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class KeyValue<K,V>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Key
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public K Key { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Value
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing **[DataContract]** and **[DataMember]** attributes on your class and KeyValuePair property. You'll need to add a reference to **System.Runtime.Serialization**.  Keep in mind you may also need to apply these attributes at the base class level for serialization to work.

```
[DataContract]
public class KeyValue : ProfileBase
{
    public KeyValue() { }

    [DataMember]
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> KV
    {
        get { return (KeyValuePair<string, string>)base["KV"]; }
        set { base["KV"] = value; }
    }            
}
```